# How to clip many lines with polygon?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have two vector layers:

- "parallel": a vector layer containing a lot of lines, they're all parallel but that shouldnt matter
- "polygon": a vector layer with just 1 polygon

I want to create a new layer with the clipped lines in it. So only the part of the lines inside the polygon (easy clip function).

I'm using the "qgis:clip" function, which is pretty easy.
At first I failed beceause I didnt knew that this clip function expects you to select the features (of the line layer), and doesn't just automatically clips ALL the features in the layer.

After I found that out, I restarted but I still can't get it to work ...

```
parallel = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("parallel")[0]
polygon = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]

selection = []
for feature in parallel.getFeatures():
    selection.append(feature.id())
    parallel.setSelectedFeatures(selection)


processing.runalg("qgis:clip", parallel, polygon, r"C:\Users\Kristof\Desktop\Layer\c5.shp")

layer5 = iface.addVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\Kristof\Desktop\Layer\c5.shp", "c5", "ogr")
```

But I always end up with an empty vector layer ...

Comment: Do your layers have the same CRS? This is by far the most common source of error when clipping.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @KristofdeWerdt! Which QGIS version and _Processing_ plugin version are you using? I know you tagged `qgis-2.0` but I have seen people use this for the more latest versions =). Also, you should not have to select all features, this should be done automatically when no features are selected.

Comment: Hi,
I'm using the latest version of both QGIS and the Processing plugin, sorry for the wrong tag.

I just saw that I'm getting this error: Shapefiles without attribute are considered read-only.

Do you have any idea what this could mean?

I can confirm that I'm not mixing different CRS's, everything is in EPSG 3857

Comment: @KristofdeWerdt - Perhaps there are some issues with your shapefile. Could you perhaps upload it onto a public server (e.g. sharefile or dropbox) so that others could test it?